# Compare two list of dictionaries in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have two lists of dictionaries named as category and sub_category.

```
category = [{'cat_id':1,'total':300,'from':250},{'cat_id':2,'total':100,'from':150}]
```

```
sub_category = [{'id':1,'cat_id':1,'charge':30},{'id':2,'cat_id':1,'charge':20},{'id':3,'cat_id':2,'charge':30}]
```

I want to change the value for `charge` to `0` in sub_category if the value of `total >= from` in `category` where `cat_id`'s are equal.

Expected result is :

```
sub_category = [{'id':1,'cat_id':1,'charge':0},{'id':2,'cat_id':1,'charge':0},{'id':3,'cat_id':2,'charge':30}]
```

I managed to get the result by using this

```
for sub in sub_category:
    for cat in category:
        if cat['cat_id'] == sub['cat_id']:
            if cat['total'] >= cat['from']:
                sub['charge']=0
```

But I want to know the better way of doing this. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: you don't have to iterate both lists, instead iterate through the first list using  `enumerate`  and get the element from the current index of second list for comparison.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one approach. Change category to a dict for easy loopup.

**Ex:**

```
category = [{'cat_id':1,'total':300,'from':250},{'cat_id':2,'total':100,'from':150}]
sub_category = [{'id':1,'cat_id':1,'charge':30},{'id':2,'cat_id':1,'charge':20},{'id':3,'cat_id':2,'charge':30}]

category = {i.pop('cat_id'): i for i in category}

for i in sub_category:
    if i['cat_id'] in category:
        if category[i['cat_id']]['total'] >= category[i['cat_id']]['from']:
            i['charge'] = 0
print(sub_category)
```

**Output:**

```
[{'cat_id': 1, 'charge': 0, 'id': 1},
 {'cat_id': 1, 'charge': 0, 'id': 2},
 {'cat_id': 2, 'charge': 30, 'id': 3}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

I thinkt the way i did may not suitable at some cases. I like to use List Comprehensions just have a look.

```
category = [{'cat_id':1,'total':300,'from':250},{'cat_id':2,'total':100,'from':150}]
sub_category = [{'id':1,'cat_id':1,'charge':30},{'id':2,'cat_id':1,'charge':20},{'id':3,'cat_id':2,'charge':30}]
print [sub_cat if cat['cat_id'] == sub_cat['id'] and cat['total'] >= cat['from'] and not sub_cat.__setitem__('charge','0') else sub_cat for sub_cat in sub_category for cat in category]

Result:[{'cat_id': 1, 'charge': '0', 'id': 1}, {'cat_id': 1, 'charge': '0', 'id': 1}, {'cat_id': 1, 'charge': 20, 'id': 2}, {'cat_id': 1, 'charge': 20, 'id': 2}, {'cat_id': 2, 'charge': 30, 'id': 3}, {'cat_id': 2, 'charge': 30, 'id': 3}]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can solve your problem using this approach:

```
target_categories = set([elem.get('cat_id') for elem in category if elem.get('total', 0) >= elem.get('from', 0)])
if None in target_categories:
    target_categories.remove(None) # if there's no cat_id in one of the categories we will get None in target_categories. Remove it.
for elem in sub_category:
    if elem.get('cat_id') in target_categories:
        elem.update({'charge': 0})
```

Time comparison with another approach:

```
import numpy as np

size = 5000000
np.random.seed()

cat_ids = np.random.randint(50, size=(size,))
totals = np.random.randint(500, size=(size,))
froms = np.random.randint(500, size=(size,))

category = [{'cat_id': cat_id, 'total': total, 'from': from_} for cat_id, total, from_ in zip(cat_ids, totals, froms)]
sub_category = [{'id': 1, 'cat_id': np.random.randint(50), 'charge': np.random.randint(100)} for i in range(size)]

%%time
target_categories = set([elem.get('cat_id') for elem in category if elem.get('total', 0) >= elem.get('from', 0)])
if None in target_categories:
    target_categories.remove(None) # if there's no cat_id in one of the categories we will get None in target_categories. Remove it.
for elem in sub_category:
    if elem.get('cat_id') in target_categories:
        elem.update({'charge': 0})
# Wall time: 3.47 s

%%time
category = {i.pop('cat_id'): i for i in category}
for i in sub_category:
    if i['cat_id'] in category:
        if category[i['cat_id']]['total'] >= category[i['cat_id']]['from']:
            i['charge'] = 0
# Wall time: 5.73 s
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
# Input
category = [{'cat_id':1,'total':300,'from':250},{'cat_id':2,'total':100,'from':150}]
sub_category = [{'id':1,'cat_id':1,'charge':30},{'id':2,'cat_id':1,'charge':20},{'id':3,'cat_id':2,'charge':30}]

# Main code
for k in sub_category:
    if k["cat_id"] in [i["cat_id"] for i in category if i["total"] >= i["from"]]:
        k["charge"] = 0
print (sub_category)

# Output
[{'id': 1, 'cat_id': 1, 'charge': 0}, {'id': 2, 'cat_id': 1, 'charge': 0}, {'id': 3, 'cat_id': 2, 'charge': 30}]
```